# Constructing the quasinilpotent residual with GAP

Tags: gap

A (finite) quasinilpotent group $G$ is one that satisfies $\mathrm{F}^{\ast}(G)=G$, where $\mathrm{F}^{\ast}$ is the [generalised Fitting subgroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitting_subgroup#The_generalized_Fitting_subgroup) of $G$. The class of quasinilpotent groups is a formation (cf. Huppert & Blackburn Finite Groups III p.124), thus every (finite) group has a quasinilpotent residual, i.e. a smallest normal subgroup such that the quotient it affords is quasinilpotent.

My question is: how might one go about constructing the quasinilpotent residual with GAP?

Comment: There is a package FORMAT (http://www.gap-system.org/Packages/format.html) to work with formations.

Comment: I know about that particular package, but I don't quite see how to define the formation of quasinilpotent groups within it.